# Difference in memory usage when using objects vs primitive values as function arguments

Tags: javascript, memory-management

Whenever I only need one specific object property, I will pass that property to the function, but I've seen my colleagues passing the whole objects only to use 1 value. Intuitively I believe my way is better, but I'd like to really know if it's better purely from the point of memory management.

```
const largeObj = {...};

dummyFn1(largeObj);
dummyFn2(largeObj.name);
```

So in essence - is there any difference in memory allocation between these two functions?

Comment: Passing the whole object would actually be faster / better on memory,.. As your just passing a reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects are passed by reference in JavaScript, so passing an object as an argument is basically just passing a memory pointer, which is negligible.